# How to generate pfx file from spc?

Tags: certificate, mmc

We purchased a certficate from godaddy.

We need to generate pfx file from the spc file provided.

For that last time we used the process provided in this [link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698).

But, it should be done from the same machine where the certificate request is generated.

That machine is not available now.
I tried to use the process on build machine, but the options are greyed out.

[Options in mmc greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya1Ks.png)

Comment: You will have to make the machine available, or regenerate another certificate.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, private key left on the machine where original request was generated. Without the private key you can't get PFX. Until you make the machine available, the purchased certificate is useless, because it contains only public key. Alternativaly, re-create new CSR and request new certificate using another machine. You may or may not be charged for extra certificate. Contact GoDaddy support to check if you can re-request new certificate for free.

Comment: Ok, any other option?

Comment: Sorry, but no other options.

Comment: If we request a new certificate, they will charge again extra?

Comment: It depends on particular CA provider. Some CAs offer re-issuance at no charge. Contact your CA provider for more details.

Comment: My CA provider is godaddy.com

Comment: Have you contacted them? What did they say?

Comment: They are replying with the same link again.